# maven grunt jasmine front-end test integration on jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, gruntjs, jasmine, aem

I am currently attempting to integrate maven grunt jasmine on our Jenkins server. 
The expect result would be, when we run the build (in configuration we will run mvn clean install -Pgrunt) then jenkins job runs all front-end jasmine tests.

Here is my project pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>install-node</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install node and npm</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm install</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>install</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v4.6.1</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>2.15.9</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>grunt</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>grunt build</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>grunt</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

next to the pom here is my package.json

```
{
  "name":"frontend-tools",
  "version":"0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint":"~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine":"~1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

and Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

  grunt.initConfig({
    jasmine: {
      customTemplate: {
        src: 'jcr_root/apps/example/components/**/*.js',
        options: {
            specs: 'jcr_root/apps/example/components/**/spec/*.js',
            helpers: 'jcr_root/apps/example/components/**/spec/*Helper.js',
            vendor: [
                      "jcr_root/etc/designs/example/clientlibs_tools/js/jquery.js"
                    ]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jasmine');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jasmine']);

};
```

And I have a dummy test somewhere under  component/**/spec folder, say it is a dummytest.js :

```
describe("A suite", function() {
  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

And everything works fine when I running locally, mvn clean install -Pgrunt
it gives me the expected effect like this:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ app ---
[INFO] Deleting Z:\CQ5\example\app\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.1:grunt (grunt build) @ app ---
[INFO] Running 'grunt ' in Z:\CQ5\example\app
[INFO] Running "jasmine:customTemplate" (jasmine) task
[INFO]  A suite
[INFO]    - contains spec with an expectation......â??
[INFO]  A suite is just a function
[INFO]    - and so is a spec......â??
[INFO] 4 specs in 0.002s.
[INFO] >> 0 failures
[INFO]
[INFO] Done, without errors.
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But when i make a job build on jenkins based on the exactly same code and config, it becomes:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ app ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.1:grunt (grunt build) @ app ---
[INFO] Running 'grunt ' in /data/apps/jenkins/workspace/maven-grunt-jasmine-testrun/app
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.627 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-07T11:26:39+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/218M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.1:grunt (grunt build) on project app: Failed to run task: 'grunt ' failed. java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/apps/jenkins/workspace/maven-grunt-jasmine-testrun/app/node/node" (in directory "/data/apps/jenkins/workspace/maven-grunt-jasmine-testrun/app"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
```

And here is my jenkins config:
[image]

And as you can see, i am trying to test if my node npm and grunt installed correctly, here are the output info:

```
+ cd app
+ pwd
/data/apps/jenkins/workspace/maven-grunt-jasmine-testrun/app
+ npm install
npm WARN frontend-tools@0.0.1 No description
npm WARN frontend-tools@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN frontend-tools@0.0.1 No license field.
+ grunt --help
/tmp/hudson5273188301428948376.sh: line 2: grunt: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

So I just wondering, has any experts experienced this kind of configure setup before? any hints or suggestions would be great. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after research, i found that it is actually the node_modules folder is out dated, so i created another profile just to remove node_modules on jenkins.
here is the updated pom.xml  profiles:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>install-node</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install node and npm</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm install</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>install</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v4.6.1</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>2.15.9</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>remove-node-module</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <followSymLinks>false</followSymLinks>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>${basedir}/node_modules</directory>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>grunt-jenkins</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>grunt jenkins</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>grunt</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>jenkins</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

so, on jenkins, run the `mvn clean install -Pinstall-node`   to install npm
then,  mvn clean test -Pgrunt-jenkins,
if in case it fails,  run `mvn clean test -Premove-node-module`  to remove outdated node_modules
finally again run    `mvn clean test -Pgrunt-jenkins`   it builds succuessfully for me. thanks